# EU Compensation Entitlement

Tags: eu

I was booked on BA under one booking reference for a flight from Bangkok to Glasgow via Heathrow. The Heathrow Glasgow leg was cancelled at the last minute with the consequence I didn’t arrive in Glasgow until almost 24 hours after the scheduled time. BA have offered €250 compensation (I assume on the basis that the actual flight cancelled was a journey of less than 1,500km). 
My understanding of the rules are that because the flights were all under the one booking the distance should be Bangkok to Glasgow so should qualify for €600 compensation. Can you please advise who is correct. Thanks

Comment: BA flies around ten Heathrow-Glasgow flights a day. How come they couldn't get you on a flight until 24 hours later?

Comment: Laziness/incompetence, I imagine

Comment: I believe you are correct, but the regulation only requires the distance of the flight to be measured up to the final destination.  It does not say anything about where the measurement should begin.

Comment: Or even Heathrow - Edinburgh with a direct road transfer to Glasgow.

Comment: Did you accept the 250 €? If so, did you not waive the right to sue for more money?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold.